# Special Character in Ubuntu 20.04 Server OS

Tags: 20.04

Is there a way to type § into the server os Ubuntu 20.04? I haven't found anything on how to type special characters like § in terminal interface.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest way to access the section sign character would be to SSH into the machine and paste it from the remote machine, as many SSH clients support copy/paste. If you need to do this from the server itself, then you can press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd> to trigger the Unicode character input mode, then the hex code of the section sign, which is `00A7`.

You can read more about special character entry [on the Tips & Tricks](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/tips-specialchars.html.en) site and find hex codes [on CompArt](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+00A7)

Answer (score 3):

This mostly depends on how you have configured your keyboard. I have my keyboard configured with a DIN 2137-1:2012-06 T2 layout, and there, it is <kbd>⇧</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>. On a keyboard configured with the EurKEY layout, it is the dead key <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd> followed by <kbd>s</kbd>.